# Proxmox I/O Error, dev sda, sector xxxxxxxxx HP ProLiant DL360 G6

Tags: linux, hp-proliant, proxmox, io

I am running an HP Proliant DL360 G6 with 8 hard drives(SSD) installed in a RAID 5 configuration. After running for some time (a few hours to a couple of days) these errors are produced.

[Image of I/O Errors on server](https://imgur.com/a/ETOaBIS)

I access the web interface and see that the LVM is having issues. I cannot login to the actual machine or ssh into it.

[Image of VM setup with problem LVM](https://imgur.com/a/ueeQg0M)

It is in a cluster with two other servers that are reporting it as healthy.
I can provide any additional information that is needed.